# Dockerfileのbuild中にEnvironment Modulesのmoduleコマンドが使えない

Tags: docker

以下のようなDockefileを作成しました。
ここで、environmant-modules は openmpi-devel と一緒にインストールされます。
また、sourceコマンドを使うために、SHELLでbashを指定しています。

```
FROM almalinux:latest
RUN dnf -y install openmpi-devel
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
RUN module load mpi/openmpi-x86_64
CMD /bin/bash
```

これをbuildします。

```
> docker build -t test:test .
```

すると下記のようなエラーがでて、build中にmoduleコマンドを実行することができません。

```
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN module load mpi/openmpi-x86_64
------
 > [5/5] RUN module load mpi/openmpi-x86_64:
#7 0.176 /bin/bash: module: command not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -c module load mpi/openmpi-x86_64]: exit code: 127
```

一方、以下のDockerfileに対して、

```
FROM almalinux:latest
RUN dnf -y install openmpi-devel
CMD /bin/bash
```

build、runを行い。

```
> docker build -t test:test .
> docker run -it --rm test:test
```

コンテナ内でmoduleコマンドを使うと、

```
> module avail
```

下記のようにエラー無く適切な結果が得られることは確認できました。

```
----- /usr/share/Modules/modulefiles ------
dot  module-git  module-info  modules  null  use.own  
------ /etc/modulefiles ------
mpi/openmpi-x86_64  
------ /usr/share/modulefiles ------
pmi/pmix-x86_64
```

build中にも module コマンドを使う方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dockerfile リファレンス](https://docs.docker.jp/engine/reference/builder.html#id2)

> 各命令は個別に実行されます。 それによって新たなイメージがビルドされます。したがって、たとえば `RUN cd /tmp` を実行したとしても、次の命令には何の効果も与えません。

`source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh` と `module load mpi/openmpi-x86_64` は別個の `bash` プロセス内で実行されますので質問欄にあるエラーが発生することになります。なので、2行の `RUN` コマンドを1行にまとめる必要があります。

##### Dockerfile

```sh
FROM almalinux:latest
RUN dnf -y install openmpi-devel
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh && module load mpi/openmpi-x86_64
CMD /bin/bash
```

Comment: ご提案の方法で環境が正しくロードされました。
ありがとうございます。